# Error 1215 on adding foreign key. Help me with what I haven't tried

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to set a foreign key relationship between two existing table but for some reason which I'm missing I keep getting this error 1215.

The relevant fields of the two tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `approvals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_contract` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `request_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  -- more nullable columns here with no indexing/relationships
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `approval_id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `version` (`version`,`lang`,`id_contract`),
  CONSTRAINT `approval_id_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) 
      REFERENCES `users` (`iduser`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1079 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
CREATE TABLE `version` (
  `idversion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idcontract` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idversion`,`idcontract`,`language`),
  KEY `fk_version_contracts_idx` (`idcontract`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_kidversion_contracts` FOREIGN KEY (`idcontract`) 
      REFERENCES `contracts` (`id_contract`) 
      ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**What have I tried**
First thing I checked is the persistency:

```
SELECT * FROM approvals a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM version v 
    WHERE v.idcontract = a.id_contract AND v.language = a.lang 
        AND v.idversion = a.version);
```

which resulted in 0 rows returned out of 701, ok my db should be good from the data pov.

So I checked the collation and for some reason the version table was latin1 vs utf8_generic_ci, ok so I restored the version table to utf8 with this.

```
ALTER TABLE `kidversion` 
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

-- and for good measure
ALTER TABLE `kidversion` 
CHANGE COLUMN `language` `language` VARCHAR(8) 
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL;
```

But at this point I'm still getting an error while trying to create the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `approvals` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `approval_ibfk_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`version` , `lang` , `id_contract`)
  REFERENCES `version` (`idversion` , `language` , `idcontract`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

And that results in a 1215 in every step I made. Surely I'm missing something.. can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOREIGN KEY (`version` , `lang` , `id_contract`) REFERENCES `version` (`idversion` , `language` , `idcontract`) AND  PRIMARY KEY (`idversion`,`idcontract`,`language`) don't match fields have to be in the same order as well as same type.
'In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Oh..... so workbench was generating the constraints in the wrong order then... makes sense, ty for the tip, I would have never guessed it.